Bash deploy script only works the first time?
This script works perfectly the first time after starting it but when it's done it only continues to output zip_count: 0 afterwards. There seems to be some strange cache?
I run the script inside Git Bash on Windows 2016
I have tried: hash -r inside each function that seems cached and instead set +h inside the functions, I added local prefix to variables, nothing helps, it doesn't see any new zip files for some reason.. Below is the relevant parts of the script.
UPDATE: This script looks for a single *.zip file inside the folder $DROP_AREA, when it finds one it should automatically run scripts that deploy this code on the server, this includes taking backups and afterwards removing the zip file and the unzipped folder.
$(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l) is not stored in variable and repeated to try and get around the weird caching issue but it did not help.. I used to store it in a variable inside the fn.
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Base directory of the scripts
clear
BASE_DEPLOY_DIR="/d/DropArea/Automation-Deployment"

echo "Which project?"
cd /d/DropArea/Automation-Deployment/projects
values=$(ls -p | grep -v / | grep -v "_server.sh$")
readarray -t values <<<"$values"
select word in "${values[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z "$word" ]]; then
        printf '"%s" is not a valid choice\n' "$REPLY" >&2
    else
        user_in="$(( REPLY - 1))"
        break
    fi
done
project=$(echo ${values[$user_in]} | cut -d '.' -f 1)

echo "$project:"
. ./_server.sh
. ./$project.sh
echo "NO_WEB_FRONTS: $NO_WEB_FRONTS"
echo "BACKUP_FRONT[$1]: ${BACKUP_FRONT[$1]}"
echo

if [[ -z "$DROP_AREA" ]]; then
    echo "\$DROP_AREA is not set."
    exit 1
fi
cd "$DROP_AREA"

DIR="$DROP_AREA"

wait_for_upload() {
    set +h
    while true; do
        local SAMPLE1=$(ls -l --full-time "$FILE")
        sleep 5
        local SAMPLE2=$(ls -l --full-time "$FILE")
        if [ "$SAMPLE1" == "$SAMPLE2" ]; then
            break
        fi
    done
}

check_for_zip_and_deploy() {
    set +h
    echo "zip_count: $(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l)"
    if [ "$(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "There are more than one zip file in DIR: $DIR, please see so there is only 1 at the time, exiting."
        exit 1
    elif [ "$(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then
        FILE=$(ls -t "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)
        FILE=$(echo "$FILE" | tr -d '\n')
        echo "Waiting for upload to complete"
        wait_for_upload
        echo "Upload seems done"
        deploy
    fi
}

deploy() {
    set +h
    local latest_zip=$(ls -t "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)
    local latest_zip=$(echo "$latest_zip" | tr -d '\n')
    local latest_zip=$(basename "$latest_zip")
    local current_datetime=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if [ -n "$latest_zip" ]; then
        echo "$current_datetime The latest zip file is: $latest_zip"
    else
        echo "$current_datetime No zip files found in $DIR."
    fi

    local zip="$latest_zip"
    local folder=$(basename "$zip" .zip)
    cd "$PWD"

    if [ "$NO_WEB_FRONTS" == "1" ]; then
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/3-deploy.sh" 0
        echo "$current_datetime Remove unzipped deploy folder: $DROP_AREA/$folder/"
        directory_path="$DROP_AREA/$folder"
        escaped_directory_path=$(printf "%q" "$directory_path")
        bash_command="rm -rf $escaped_directory_path"
        eval "$bash_command"
        echo
        echo "$current_datetime Remove zip file"
        rm -f "$DROP_AREA/$zip"
        echo
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/scripts/cleanup_old_backups.sh" 0
        echo "$current_datetime DONE!"
        echo
    else
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/3-deploy.sh" 0
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/scripts/cleanup_old_backups.sh" 0
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/3-deploy.sh" 1
        . "$BASE_DEPLOY_DIR/scripts/cleanup_old_backups.sh" 1
        echo "$current_datetime Remove zip file"
        rm -f "$DROP_AREA/$zip"
        echo
        rm -f "$latest_zip"
        echo "$current_datetime Remove unzipped deploy folder: $DROP_AREA/$folder/"
        directory_path="$DROP_AREA/$folder"
        escaped_directory_path=$(printf "%q" "$directory_path")
        bash_command="rm -rf $escaped_directory_path"
        eval "$bash_command"
        echo
        echo "$current_datetime DONE!"
        echo
    fi
}

main_loop() {
    while true; do
        check_for_zip_and_deploy
        sleep 10
    done
}
main_loop


Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include some more information on what you script is intended to do, and what strategy it follows does so. While contributors can in principle deduce this from the code itself, this is cumbersome and error-prone without further knowledge of the original intention behind each step.

ok, for one, cd "$DROP_AREA"; DIR="$DROP_AREA" looks odd, since if the path is relative, it's likely that $DIR won't be a valid path after the cd. E.g. if DROP_AREA=foo/bar, then after the cd, $DIR would refer to foo/bar/foo/bar as seen from the starting point. With absolute paths, it should work, but then what's the point of both cd and the variable containing the path? You could just cd and then use ., or not cd and then use the absolute path.

cd "$PWD" in deploy looks like a no-op, but if it does do something, is the script left in the correct directory later? You have a few repetitions of $(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l) or variants, and those should probably be shoved into functions to avoid the repetition (and then you could more easily implement them without ls, since it's the shell that does the main work of expanding the wildcard there anyway). Trimming newlines off the result of $(foo | head -n1) shouldn't be required since the command substitution removes trailing newlines anyway.

You might want to try running the script with set -x in effect: that way you would see the commands it actually runs, which might help in figuring out what exactly goes wrong

"You have a few repetitions of $(ls "$DIR"/*.zip 2>/dev/null | wc -l)" this was to try to get around the caching issue...

set -x which @ilkkachu suggested for debugging really helped! It turns out that I had accidentally used the variable DIR for something else in another script which overwrote it after the initial run, so it started looking in the wrong folder for zip files after the initial run. The variable $DROP_AREA already had the correct location so I just replaced DIR with $DROP_AREA in this script and everything started woerking!
TLDR check that your variables are either scoped or uniquely named from all the files that consists of your script :)
